# Collection of Check Boxes for Self-referential HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `User` model in my app.  Some users are going to be clients, others team members, others admin.  (This is all handled via boolean values within the model.

I have a page (accessible only to admin) on which an administrator should be able to assign one or more `clients` to each `team` (member).

I have the HABTM association set up properly (I think) in the `user.rb` model like this:

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many(:users,
    :join_table => "team_assignments",
    :foreign_key => "team_id",
    :association_foreign_key => "client_id")
```

I have the associated params permitted in my `sign_up_params` and `account_update_params` in my Devise `registrations_controller.rb` like this:

```
def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      ...
      :team_id,
      :client_id,
      user_ids: []
    )
  end
```

It appears to work on the back end and when I set the relationships within the console.  The problem happens when I try to update the relationships using a form on the admin control page:

```
<% @teams.each do |user| %>

        <%= simple_form_for(user, :url => user_registration_path, method: :patch) do |f| %>
          
           ...

            <div class="form-inputs row mx-3 mb-5">
              <div class="col-12">
                <h2 class="color-red">Clients</h2>
                  <div class="field form-check">
                    <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:user_ids, User.all, :id, :full_name ) %>
                  </div>
              </div>

              ...

        <% end %>

<% end %>
```

When this form is submitted, it updates the correct clients (the ones you check on the form) but they are all assigned to the user that is *currently logged in* not to the team member for whom the form is generated.

Can anyone see how I can fix this?

Comment: We need to see the entire controller and the route as the issue is most likely not really due to these inputs. Also if you're using SimpleForm you can use `<%= f.association :users, collection: User.all, label_method: :name, as: :checkboxes %>` instead of the normal Rails helper to get it add the wrappers for you. https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form#associations

Comment: But I'm guessing here from the name of the path helper that you're trying to shoehorn this into the controller provided by Devise. This isn't a good idea as its solely indended to modify the *current user* and making it do otherwise will be a lot more complex then just creating a separate UsersController that is used to CRUD *other* users.